# 12.04 upgrade hosed my system

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I wish I could be more specific.  I installed the upgrade from the update manager and after the computer rebooted, I found I could not run a lot of programs.  I tried running them from the command line to see what errors I would get:

update-manager:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 32, in 
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 36, in 
    import apt
ImportError: No module named apt
```

so I need to install python-apt, right?:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
python-apt is already the newest version.
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  amarok: Depends: phonon-backend-xine but it is not installable or
                   phonon-backend
          Depends: libmtp8 (>= 0.3.1) but it is not installable
          Recommends: kdemultimedia-kio-plugins (>= 4:4.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
[300+ lines omitted]
```

It looks like I was half way through the upgrade when something broke.  apt-get -f install gives the same errors as above.  I have tried a few commands from the forums all with no luck so far:

```
apt-get install -o APT::Immediate-Configure=false -f apt python-minimal
  ran into the same dependencies problem
removing 3rd party sources from /etc/apt/sources.list
  these were already commented out
```

I can run synaptic, but it tells me I have 181 broken packages.  Is there any hope of restoring this system?  I would rather not reinstall from CD, but it looks like I may have to.